# Sender tag is always same data (wrong index?)

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following code for cell button:

```
    cell.buttonViewLink.addTarget(self, action: "buttonViewLinkAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    cell.buttonViewLink.tag = indexPath.item
```

So when I tap `buttonViewLinkAction` I get the correct name/image printed in `NSLog`, no matter which cell is tapped, it's always the correct data. This works great and creates another button:

```
    //get buttonViewLinkAction and copy to pasteboard
@IBAction func buttonViewLinkAction(sender: UIButton) {
    print("buttonViewLinkAction tapped")
    let face = self.faces[sender.tag]
    if let imageNAME: String = String(face.name){
        print(imageNAME .uppercaseString)
    }
    if let imageURL = NSURL(string:face.image) {
        print(imageURL)
    }

    UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard().string = face.directLink

    let alertView = SCLAlertView()
    alertView.addButton("Add [img] tags", target:self, selector:Selector("imgtagAction:"))
    alertView.showSuccess((face.name), subTitle: "Image link copied to clipboard")

}
```

But when I tap `imgtagAction`, I always get the data from cell 1.

```
    //get imgtagAction click
func imgtagAction(sender: UIButton!) {
    print("imgtagAction tapped")
    let face = self.faces[sender.tag]

    if let imageNAME: String = String(face.name){
        print(imageNAME .uppercaseString)
    }
    if let imageURL = NSURL(string:face.image) {
        print(imageURL)
    }
    UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard().string = "[img]" + face.directLink + "[/img]"
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You never set any tag for the `SCLAlertView` button.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, that's exactly what it was. I now know how multiple buttons with tags work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As rmaaddy commented you haven't set tag with your button and I think it is may be not possible to set tag to that custom `AlertView` button action, So I think you need to declare one `Int` instance property and set its value inside `buttonViewLinkAction` method and then use that instance inside `imgtagAction` method like this.

```
var selectedItem = 0
```

Now set `selectedItem` value inside `buttonViewLinkAction` method.

```
@IBAction func buttonViewLinkAction(sender: UIButton) {
    self.selectedItem = sender.tag
    //Your other code
}
```

Now use this `selectedItem` inside `imgtagAction` method.

```
func imgtagAction(sender: UIButton!) {
    let face = self.faces[selectedItem]
}
```